# I want to show continue message skip last one while generating pdf using dompdf in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I tried this code but this code skip the first one , but i  want if pdf pages are more than 1 than show continue.. skip last one

```
 $dompdf =new PDF(); $dompdf->load_html($html);
 $dompdf->render();
 $pageCount = $dompdf->getCanvas()->get_page_count();
 if ($pageCount > 1) {
 for ($pageNumber = 1; $pageNumber <= $pageCount; $pageNumber++) {
       $canvas = $dompdf->getCanvas($pageNumber);
       if ($pageNumber != $pageCount) {
         $canvas->text(520, 780, "Continue...", null, 10, array(0, 0, 0));
       }
     }
 }

 $output=$dompdf->output();
```